# iOS: In iOS what is the best way to deal with a database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database

Hello I was wondering what is the best way to deal with an external database on a server, like a local database on apache. Or similar when you use MYSQL. I guess I am confused how to do database work on iOS.

Thank you, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use a database *locally* (as in, one running on the same phone)? Or are you trying to connect across the Internet to, say, a database server that's shared by all the users of your app? Those are two totally different situations, with quite different answers.

Comment: Indeed, I would recommend reformulating this question as in either case it is a good one with frequently changing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't direct access MYSQL in iOS, although you are able to do it.
Apple won't approve your app.

So we are using [Web Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/UsingWebservices/Introduction/Introduction.html) to access the data. That mean you request your web server by specfic URL and parameters. And let your web server to query your db, and finally output them in `plaintext`, `XML` or `JSON` formats. When you got the result, you can `parse` it into an object like `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`.

I believe the most common way of doing this is using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) framework. It is fast and reliable. (Although ASIHTTPRequest had been stopped)

Let say you are using PHP on an apache server.

## For php - api.php:

```
$mysqlArray = mysql_query($query);
$resultObjs = array();
while($mysqlObj = mysql_fetch_object($mysqlArray)){
    array_push($resultObjs,$mysqlObj);
}

echo json_encode($mysqlObj);
```

## For get the data with ASIHTTPRequest

```
NSURL *api = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YOURSERVER.com/api.php"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:api];
NSString *resultString = [request responseString];
[request release];
```

## To parse it into an object using `SBJson`

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray *resultObjs = (NSArray*)[parser objectWithString:resultString];
[parser release];
```

This is a basic concept, read more example on their homepage and google some more examples.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Parse.com provides some interesting options in this area - you can upload a csv and create a relational DB with it, then access it through their SDK in your app, all in just a couple of lines of code.

I don't work for them but it's definitely worth checking out as a solution.

Comment: I am kind of new to this, sorry for my ignorance, but what does "csv" stand for? Thanks Tom!

Comment: just like @MaxGabriel said, in your context a csv file is a flat file with the values which are to be stored in your database.  For a new DB user, csv files can often be obtained from data generated in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

As Tom Jowett pointed before, if you are not sure what you really need, start with Parse.

If you need to persist data locally (meaning on the phone), then Core Data is excellent. Core Data is not strictly an ORM, but a graph manager, but it will store data locally for you (and you don't have to worry about the actual db). You can also use SQLite directly, but you shouldn't (unless you have a really good reason to do that).

On the other hand, if you are going to just consume data from a server, then give parse.com a look, and if doesn't fits your needs, you can always write your own RESTful server, and use the db of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use PHP pages on your server and reference them with GET variables through `NSURLConnection`. You could use an API, but this solution is much simpler.

If you need to get information from the server you could simply do the following:

```
NSString* returnedInfo = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/myaccessorpage.php?a=sdf&s=dfg"]];
```

You can run it on a background thread to avoid app hanging as well.

This may not be the most efficient way to achieve what you are doing, but it is definitely the easiest way.

Hope this helps you get started.